# RoR: Pushing to production and can't access image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rmagick, gruff

Ruby on rails app that creates a dynamic image only shows on development but not on production. Here is the controller:

```
def show
  require 'gruff'
  g = Gruff::Pie.new
  g.title = "Percentages of Fees"
  g.data 'Management Fees', mf_percent
  g.data 'Other Fees', of_percent
  file_name = 'app/assets/images/pie_charts/portfolio_' + @portfolio.id.to_s + '.png'
  g.write(file_name)
end
```

And here is the view:

```
<%= file_name = 'pie_charts/portfolio_' + @portfolio.id.to_s + '.png' %>
<%= image_tag(file_name, height: 300 ) %>
```

Now it works on development, but not in production.

Production HTML:

```
pie_charts/portfolio_3.png
<img height="300" src="/images/pie_charts/portfolio_3.png" alt="Portfolio 3">
```

Development HTML

```
pie_charts/portfolio_3.png
<img height="300" src="/assets/pie_charts/portfolio_3-8ea1d8e07ae40e233bd7366c24bc657795b6fba09095335ca0211cef72a07d3a.png" alt="Portfolio 3 8ea1d8e07ae40e233bd7366c24bc657795b6fba09095335ca0211cef72a07d3a">
```

Tried changing `file_name` to:

```
file_name = "public/images/pie_charts/portfolio_" + @portfolio.id.to_s + '.png'
```

and got this error:

```
F, [2015-08-29T02:09:19.026907 #92497] FATAL -- : 
Magick::ImageMagickError (WriteBlob Failed `public/images/pie_charts/portfolio_3.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1630):
app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:42:in `show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the production you must write it to the `public` folder.

```
def show
  require 'gruff'
  g = Gruff::Pie.new
  g.title = "Percentages of Fees"
  g.data 'Management Fees', mf_percent
  g.data 'Other Fees', of_percent
  file_name = "#{Rails.root}/public/images/pie_charts/portfolio_" + @portfolio.id.to_s + '.png'
  g.write(file_name)
end
```

In production environment the main asset folder for Rails it's public. All assets from `app/assets` and `vendor/assets` compiled to the production placed in `public/assets`

Comment: Im having a error now... `Magick::ImageMagickError (WriteBlob Failed` Any ideas?

Comment: show full error trace please, and try to omit `Rails.root` from `"public/images/pie_charts/portfolio_"`

Comment: @CameronAziz do you already have a `images/pie_charts/` folder?